# Buttons and Labels Will Not Show Up in Window

Tags: python, tkinter

The buttons and labels will not show up in my window. If I delete self from the parenthesis (or insert controller instead), the buttons will show up. However, the buttons do not raise the underlying window to the front as it is supposed to. I used a similar code that used pack, and it worked well. I can't seem to find the problem of why using grid won't work. I'm a bit of a beginner to tkinter so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

```
import tkinter as tk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT= ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT= ("Verdana", 8)


class mGui(tk.Tk):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs): 

       tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kargs) 
       container = tk.Frame(self)
       container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
       container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

       self.frames = {}  

       for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")



       self.show_frame(StartPage)   

    def show_frame(self, cont):  
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()   


class StartPage(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):  
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label_1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Start Page", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0) 


        button1 = tk.Button(self,text = "Go", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)     

class PageOne(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label_1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Page One", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label_1.grid(row = 1, column = 4)  

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go Back", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row = 4, column = 1)              


app = mGui()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a call to the `grid()` layout manager for the `container` `Frame` as shown:

```
         .
         .
         .

class mGui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):

       tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
       container = tk.Frame(self)
       container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
       container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

       container.grid()  # ADD THIS.

         .
         .
         .
```